# Batch script for time measurement not working properly

Tags: time, batch-file, measurement

I'm using a batch script for the time measurement of commands. I have found this script here on StackOverflow. Unfortunately it sometimes is not working properly and unfortunately I don't know much about batch programming. I get the impression that it sometimes works and sometimes not. Perhaps I err on this but it does seem that its not working properly after midnight.

The script:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem The format of %TIME% is HH:MM:SS,CS for example 23:59:59,99
set STARTTIME=%TIME%

rem here begins the command you want to measure
dir /s > nul
rem here ends the command you want to measure

set ENDTIME=%TIME%

echo STARTTIME %STARTTIME%

rem convert STARTTIME and ENDTIME to centiseconds

set /A STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%STARTTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%STARTTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%STARTTIME:~9,2%-100)

echo STARTTIME %STARTTIME%

echo ENDTIME %ENDTIME%

set /A ENDTIME=(1%ENDTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%ENDTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%ENDTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%ENDTIME:~9,2%-100)

echo ENDTIME %ENDTIME%

rem calculating the duration is easy
set /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%

rem we might have measured the time inbetween days
if %ENDTIME% LSS %STARTTIME% set set /A DURATION=%STARTTIME%-%ENDTIME%

rem outputing

echo DURATION: %DURATION% in centiseconds

endlocal
goto :EOF
```

I was using it half an hour ago and I got this result:

```
STARTTIME  1:29:25.17 
STARTTIME  1:29:25.17 
ENDTIME  1:29:27.82 
ENDTIME  1:29:27.82 
DURATION: 1 in centiseconds
```

So something with the lines

```
set /A STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%STARTTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%STARTTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%STARTTIME:~9,2%-100)
```

and

the line

```
set /A ENDTIME=(1%ENDTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000 + (1%ENDTIME:~3,2%-100)*6000 + (1%ENDTIME:~6,2%-100)*100 + (1%ENDTIME:~9,2%-100)
```

seems to be wrong.

What is it?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `"%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100"` being `" 1"`, there is an extra space. The program then tries to find the value of `(1 1)` instead of `(101)`.

The extra 1 in front should only be for systems that output the time as `"01:29:25.17"` (to give 101 instead of 01 which the system will interpret as octal number), but for systems that output the time as `" 1:29:25.17"`(Note the space in front of the 1) there is a problem (which will give `1 1`).

An easy way is just to remove the 1 in `STARTTIME=(1%STARTTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000` and `ENDTIME=(1%ENDTIME:~0,2%-100)*360000`, though that might cause a problem with other systems.

A more watertight solution would be to add two lines after the rem line:

```
rem convert STARTTIME and ENDTIME to centiseconds

set STARTTIME=%STARTTIME: =0%

set ENDTIME=%ENDTIME: =0%
```

(EDIT: Andriy M's much shorter method above)

---

There are also two `set` in `if %ENDTIME% LSS %STARTTIME% set set /A DURATION=%STARTTIME%-%ENDTIME%` which might cause a problem when trying to measure the time between days.

Comment: +1, although, instead of checking for the presence of a space, you could just replace it with a `0` unconditionally: `SET "STARTTIME=%STARTTIME: =0%"` and same for `ENDTIME`. That way, if you put that immediately before the calculations, you could leave the rest of the code untouched.

Comment: Good idea, I edited it. I was thinking leading 0's will specify octal notation, which most probably is the purpose of the 1 in front.